# Mark a center point on rectangle or circle shapes in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am trying to make a cut template in photoshop. So I have to draw a rectangle and mark a center point on that shape (Cross or small circle). Which is the accurate way to do that. I emphasized accurate because its cut template.

Comment: Have you tried alignment tools like align horizontal and vertical?

Comment: @Vikas Sorry bro.. I am not.. I am not so fluent in PS

Comment: It *may* be more productive to do this in illustrator and then copypaste it to PS later.

Comment: What do you mean by "cut template"?   Is it for a cutting machine?  If so, I wouldn't use Photoshop. Better to use a vector image editor such as Illustrator, CorelDraw, Inkscape, etc.

Comment: @BillyKerr Sorry for confusing.. Its just for manual cutting on wooden sheet

Comment: If thats the case then you would be much more productive in future  using a vector application (Illustrator, Inkscape...). Or a CAD application (which is a more intelligent vector application for this kind of usecase). I mean sure you can use photoshop in much the same way as i can use mouse traps for hunting birds. Its well worth the effort as its not only faster its also more intuitive and more usable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Photoshop alignment tools. Create a circle in separate layer that you want to place in center.

Move the circle manually in approximate center of the rectangle (if your *rectangle* contains multiple paths/shapes, group them all). Then you select your rectangle and circle layers, and click align horizontal and align vertical button on this toolbar:

[image]

Something like this. You can use symbol like X and later guides for more *visual* accuracy of center.

[image]

(Make sure there is no any other object outside your rectangle boundary, otherwise you likely won't get intended result).

---

A mathematical solution would be to draw two diagonals and the intersection would be the *center*.